# Evitar auto cálculo del timezone en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Como hago para al recibir una fecha y hora (Desde un campo en timestamp) cuando devuelvo al cliente, éste automáticamente me hace el cálculo del Timezone (GMT -5). Ej. Si en la base de datos tengo 00:05:32 (formato horas, minutos y segundos), cuando lo muestro en el cliente, me muestra 05:05:32 (Ya que yo estoy en Perú y aquí es GMT -5) Espero sus comentarios.

**[Edito]**

Estoy enviando la data desde Node usando socket.io.

En la base de datos tengo:

```
2016-10-31 00:05:10
```

En Javascript uso:

```
new Date(Date.parse(obj.hora_inicio)).toUTCString()
```

Esto me devuelve:

> "Mon, 31 Oct 2016 15:18:45 GMT"

Bueno creo que va peor la cosa no? realmente estoy confundido.

Comment: Hola! Puedes poner parte del código que tienes para así, basar nuestras respuestas sobre ese código y que todo sea más claro?

Comment: Estoy enviando la data desde Node usando socket.io.. En la base de datos tengo: 2016-10-31 00:05:10

En Javascript uso: 

new Date(Date.parse(obj.hora_inicio)).toUTCString()

Esto me devuelve:

"Mon, 31 Oct 2016 15:18:45 GMT"

Bueno creo que va peor la cosa no? realmente estoy confundido

Comment: De acuerdo, añádelo editando tu pregunta para que quede más claro

Comment: Mil disculpas, presioné Enter antes de terminar.. acabo de editar mi respuesta anterior. Lo añadiré al código principal.

Comment: si quieres solo la hora de la base de datos, por que no quitas el `toUTCString()` ?

Comment: En realidad en todos los casos que esto probando me devuelve siempre lo mismo: "Mon Oct 31 2016 10:18:45 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacífico, Sudamérica)". ¿Porqué lo uso? porque antes de postear mi pregunta busqué y vi algunas soluciones que en mi caso no funcionó.

Comment: Ricki, la solucion definitiva a este problema es guardar en la base de datos las fechas en formato UTC y luego dejar que cada navedor represente la hora local del usuario, asi todos los usuarios ven un horario corrdinado, no importa donde se encuentren. Salu2

Comment: hey @rnd revisa la respuesta que acabo de publicar :D

Comment: @fredyfx la vi y no lo pongo en respuesta por que no tengo el tiempo de elaborarlo. No dudo que sea posible, pero es una cuestion de equilibrio entre esfuerzo y ventajas. Usar UTC y dejar que el browser use la forma local es una forma simple de resolverlo. Igual estaria bien usar moment para muchas otras cosas que hacen falta en cualquier sistema que use fechas, pero la "sincronizacion" de las fechas viene desde el diseño y no desde la presentacion. Prefiero los diseños simples. XD

Comment: @rnd sos un capo hermano! gracias por el comentario :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamentablemente no se puede cambiar este comportamiento del JavaScript (de manera nativa), el motivo es porque JavaScript tiene 1 sola manera de trabajar las fechas/horas by default (por así decirlo).

Lo que ocurre es simplemente que Javascript mira al cambio de hora, calcula la fecha y hora, y luego le pide al sistema operativo para la representación de esta marca de tiempo en la zona horaria local.

**El sistema operativo proporciona un servicio para mostrar la hora en la zona horaria local, pero no en otras zonas horarias**. Para ello hay que tener en cuenta cosas como el horario de verano...

Como siempre con la gestión del tiempo, la única manera decente de hacer frente a este problema es utilizar una biblioteca dedicada. En Javascript tenemos a **[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)** y **[Moment.Timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)** una librería que entra a ser la salvadora de los problemas con conflictos de zonas horarias.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
console.log((moment('2016-10-31 00:05:10')).format('L'));
console.log((moment('2016-10-31 00:05:10')).format('LL'));
console.log((moment('2016-10-31 00:05:10')).format('LLL'));
console.log((moment('2016-10-31 00:05:10')).format('LLLL'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Lo interesante es que si necesitas mandar a otras zonas horarias, puedes hacerlo con facilidad, de la misma manera hacer un formato con las diversas opciones que hay en **Moment.JS**

Y como diríamos en Perú: "De yapa" (ref: agregando algo extra)

Esta librería utiliza la **norma ISO 8601**, donde la fecha se puede definir en un momento preciso (como los cambios de zona horaria +/- 1hora) y por lo tanto se mostrará en todas las zonas horarias que desees.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información tan util que has compartido conmigo, saludos!

Comment: de nada hermano, estamos para servir. También considera el comentario de @rnd : http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30902/evitar-auto-c%c3%a1lculo-del-timezone-en-javascript/30918#comment50466_30902 tiene un buen punto de vista. saludos :D

Comment: Cierto, realmente es una forma simple. Por el momento envié la hora, minuto y segundo por separado usando la función TIME de MySQL para que Node simplemente me los envíe como datos planos y yo poder cogerlos en el cliente y hacer lo que quiero. Bueno, funcionó (me sacó del apuro) pero entiendo que sus propuestas evidentemente son mas profesionales. Gracias a ambos!